# take title of sub link on home page

Tags: selenium

i've aready got the sub link on the homepage. But try to take title for each sub link.
Can anyone help me! thanks you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

tem_data = {'URL':[],  #make database,
           'Title':[]}

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://m.cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/minivelobike")
URL = ([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='txt_area' and @href]")))])

Title = "some code to get 'tit"  #get title of each URL[enter image description here][1]

tem_data['URL'].append(URL)
tem_data['Title'].append(Title)
print(tem_data)

Keyword_seach=('xxx.db')
```

Comment: you should refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146031/how-to-extract-href-link-title-with-selenium)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below should get you the titles:

```py
Title = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "strong.tit")]
```

The thing about Korean characters is that if you want to view them in your terminal, you will need to [set your output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573649/10537391):

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
print(tem_data['Title'])
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks you!